# Exlude parts of spring context in tests

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to exclude some parts of my spring context when testing my components/repos etc that doesn't need for web, security etc to be loaded.

Is there a easy way to exclude them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a custom configuration for your tests:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

> you may be used to using @ContextConfiguration(classes=…​) in order to specify which Spring @Configuration to load